# How is the Law site for StackExchange different from the new Politics one?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know how to differentiate between the two StackExchange sites, "Law" and "Politics". For example, where would I rather post a question such as, "Does the President have free rein to discredit the mass media?" I see a legal element to the question, but at the same time it might also be considered of a political nature!

Comment: I think either site is fine for a q like this; laws that affect the POTUS are definitely on-topic here on Politics. (The problem I had with your question was that I found the formulation confusing.)

Comment: We already discussed this question of scope before. I linked this question to the last one. tl;dr version: Law.SE is for asking "what is the law?" and PoliticsSE is for asking "why is this the law?". Questions about laws which affect political processes can be asked on either site. By the way: Politics Stack Exchange is actually a few years older than Law Stack Exchange.